# How to display all errors on submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I will like to know how can I display all of my validated errors at once when user submit a form. Until here, it works fine but it shows the errors one by one.

```
const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
let errorMessages = [
                    "please fill in your name here", 
                    "please, fill in your email correct here", 

                    ];
const reg = /^\d+$/;

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    if(valName.value !== ''){
        valName.nextElementSibling.textContent = '';
        valName.className = '';
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        valName.nextElementSibling.textContent = errorMessages[0];
        valName.className = 'errorborder';
        return false;
    }
    if(valEmail.value.indexOf('@') != -1 && this.value.indexOf('.') != -1){
        valEmail.nextElementSibling.textContent = '';
        valEmail.className = '';
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        valEmail.nextElementSibling.textContent = errorMessages[1];
        valEmail.className = 'errorborder';
        return false;
    }
});
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you ever heard of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)? Whenever you see a pattern (such as you have in your `else` block statements), there's a chance you can rewrite your code more dynamically. Try to find a way to write `e.preventDefault();`, `valEmail.nextElementSibling.textContent = errorMessages[1];` `valEmail.className = 'errorborder';`, `return false;
` only once. What's different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove your returns - otherwise the code will stop there. 
I have also moved codes into functions instead of copying.

```
    const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    let errorMessages = [
                        "please fill in your name here", 
                        "please, fill in your email correct here", 

                        ];

    const reg = /^\d+$/;

    function isEmailValid(email){
        return email.indexOf('@') != -1 && email.indexOf('.') != -1;
    }

    function isNameValid(name){
        return name !== ''
    }

    function setErrorMessage(el, errorMessage){
        el.nextElementSibling.textContent = errorMessage;
        el.className = 'errorborder';
    }

    function clearError(el){
        el.nextElementSibling.textContent = '';
        el.className = '';
    }

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        var validName = isNameValid(valName.value);
        var validEmail = isEmailValid(valEmail.value);

        if(!validName){
            setErrorMessage(valName, errorMessages[0]); 
        }else{
            clearError(valName);
        }

        if(!validEmail){
            setErrorMessage(valEmail, errorMessages[1]); 
        }else{
            clearError(valEmail);
        }

        if(!validName || !validEmail) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Comment: hi @Lasse, i just tried your code it works good many thanks!  but now it shows just  the `errorMessages[0]` in all error messages

Comment: Hello, it should be working now - in the setErrorMessage-function it said errorMessages[0] instead of errorMessage :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the errors in a string variable and display all of them at once.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        var errors = "";
        if(valName.value !== ''){
                    valName.nextElementSibling.textContent = '';
                    valName.className = '';
                }
                else{
                    e.preventDefault();
                    errors += errorMessages[0];
                }
                if(valEmail.value.indexOf('@') != -1 && this.value.indexOf('.') != -1){
                    valEmail.nextElementSibling.textContent = '';
                    valEmail.className = '';
                }else{
                    e.preventDefault();
                    errors += errorMessages[1];

                }
            if(errors !== ""){
               valName.className = 'errorborder';
               valName.nextElementSibling.textContent = errors.
               return false;
            }
    })
```

Comment: thank you @Amal ! it works fine the only problem is now.... the errors variable will show all erros inside and ignore  statement above . exemplo: `code` if(valName.value !== ''){
     valName.nextElementSibling.textContent = '';
     valName.className = '';
    } `code`